# Google App Engine: how to generate discovery doc for iOS (gradle build)?

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio, gradle, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using Android Studio to develop my ( GAE + Cloud Endpoints ) server, and I need to generate a discovery doc for iOS.

[Google doc: Generating Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/gen_clients) shows two ways to generate discovery doc for iOS:

> 1. using Maven

My backend project is developed in Studio and build by gradle, so I can not take this option.

> 2. using endpoints.sh (Change directory to the parent directory of your project's /war directory.)

I do not have the */war* directory in my gradle build structure.

How do I generate client-library for iOS ? Can any one help with this?

Comment: You can probably build war with gradle using `gradle war` and then under build you will have a directory that mirrors the war structure. Enter this directory and run appropriate script.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Opal, with `gradle war` I got a `war/MANIFEST.MF` in my tmp directory, but that's all, can't use it to `endpoints.sh`. And with `gradle :backend:war` I can build a `backend.war` in my `libs/`. But none of them are correct to run `endpoints.sh`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Opal!

after running `gradle war` there is a generated directory called `backend/build/discovery-docs` which contains:

1. apiname-v1-rest.discovery
2. apiname-v1-rpc.discovery

so I got discovery doc for iOS, there is no need to run :

> 2. using endpoints.sh (Change directory to the parent directory of your project's /war directory.)